# Pass Authorization Header in OpenAPI Generator-generated Java WebClient Code

Tags: java, openapi-generator, spring-resttemplate, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have a Java/Spring-based microservices architecture with two services:

- A - has a public endpoint which does some stuff and then calls the below endpoint on B. This endpoint requires an Authorization header to identify the user.
- B - has an endpoint that also requires an Authorization header so that it can determine which user made the call.

My openapi secutiry scheme is:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      in: header
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
security:
  - bearerAuth: []
```

what do I need to do to pass the Authorization header along from A to B?